# uninitialized constant - totally lost with this in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, initialization, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload a file  to a form with Carrierwave, but everytime I run my rails server I am met with the following message:

NameError in ListingsController#index

uninitialized constant Listings::ImageUpLoader

**Extracted source (around line #2):**

```
 1.    class Listings < ActiveRecord::Base
 2.         mount_uploader :image, ImageUpLoader
 3.   end
```

Rails.root: C:/Sites/redemo

This is what my error log says

```
Started GET "/listings/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-06 20:09:16 +0100
Processing by ListingsController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
[1m[36mListing Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE        "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "1"]]
Rendered listings/_form.html.erb (111.0ms)
Rendered listings/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (121.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 248ms (Views: 240.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started PATCH "/listings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-06 20:09:20 +0100
Processing by ListingsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    k
```

[1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
          Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:44:in `update'


Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-   4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (146.0ms)
```

I'm totally lost on this one.  Any advice please?

Comment: I suppose `ImageUpLoader` should be `ImageUploader` with `l` in lowercase.

Comment: Thank you! This helped with that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, you must be having `CarrierWave Uploader` class defined as below:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ## ....
end
```

**Notice** the class name `ImageUploader` with `l` in *lowercase*.

BUT you are mounting the uploader as `ImageUpLoader` (**Notice `L` in capital**) which is causing the error `uninitialized constant Listings::ImageUpLoader`.

Update the code as below:

```
class Listings < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader ## ImageUploader with "l" in lowercase
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be;

```
class Listings < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: @user3714822, you can go ahead and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues:
1)
Look inside the update method of the controller : app/controllers/listings_controller.rb (line 44-45).

Check on the arguments and make sure you're passing the expected arguments.

2) uninitialized constant Listings::ImageUpLoader: Check the name in your model and compare it with your controller's index method reference.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. 1. I checked the update section, and it adheres exactly to the tutorial I was following, and it did work (with the exception of uploading the images)

Comment: 2 - I did check and saw the the L was uppercase.  Thank you.